# Passing CancellationToken to IAsyncEnumerable in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following

```
let myAsyncEnumerator: IAsyncEnumerator<'a> = getTheAsyncEnumerator()
```

But I want to be able to pass a `CancellationToken` to it which ultimately then gets passed to the underlying `IAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken)` implementation

I tried the following

```
open System.Threading.Tasks
let myAsyncEnumeratorWithCT = TaskAsyncEnumerableExtensions.WithCancellation(a, cts.Token)
```

which works, but the type of `myAsyncEnumeratorWithCT` is `ConfiguredCancellableAsyncEnumerable<'a>` and that wont cast back to an `IAsyncEnumerable<'a>`

I made a c# extension which does the job

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> WithCancellationToken<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> e, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken ct)
            {
                await foreach (var item in e.WithCancellation(ct)) 
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
    
            }
```

But how to stay in F# ?

Comment: Have you tried [TaskSeq](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.TaskSeq)?

Comment: Yes but it is not clear or implemented. from what I can see https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.TaskSeq/issues/133 & https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.TaskSeq/issues/78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried to write some code to stay in F# project only in your situation and even got some results. But I beg you to leave it as is at this point, it's definitely better to have a C# project for such things than do what I did.

Okay, before you'd go see what I wrote I want you to know these two things:

1. I'm not proud of it.
2. It's better to have surrogate C# project than have this code.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/SLAVONchick/1ac95175b2f9304b6d6af3f9be7835e5) it is.

Comment: Galliant effort there! Definitely proven it is possible to stay in F#, all be it uncomfortable. I agree a simple c# extension is not a huge issue, and this question is more academic in nature. Points awarded until someone offers a happier path.